# is this objective-c date checking method ok? code attached (getting different results)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

I'm perplexed as I'm not the method below is seemingly NOT working when looking at my application when both dates are the same Year/Month/Date/Hour/Minute/Sec, HOWEVER when I write a unit test to test it it seems to work fine.  Is the code below not robust for some reason?

Code is:

```
- (BOOL)isAfterThisDate:(NSDate*)thisDate {
    NSComparisonResult result = [self compare:thisDate];
    if (result == NSOrderedDescending) {
        NSLog(@"        - isAfterThisDate: %@ is after %@ is TRUE", [self stringSummary], [thisDate stringSummary]);
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"        - isAfterThisDate: %@ is after %@ is FALSE", [self stringSummary], [thisDate stringSummary]);
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Here's an extract from my application log (i.e. when I use this method in my application).  I was expecting this to be false like my unit test supports.

```
isAfterThisDate: Thu 03-11-2011 09:00:00 GMT+10:00 is after Thu 03-11-2011 09:00:00 GMT+10:00 is TRUE
```

For reference the helper method I used is:

```
- (NSString*) stringSummary {
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
    NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:self];
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have sub-second differences? Try logging out the date's `-timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`

Comment: oh - interesting point - I'll try this...

Comment: still an issue - did get the same values "- isAfterThisDate: Thu 03-11-2011 09:00:00 GMT+10:00 341967600 is after Thu 03-11-2011 09:00:00 GMT+10:00 341967600 is TRUE"

Comment: PS - I tried actually diff'ing the timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate values and this highlighted there was a difference  :)   NSTimeInterval diff = self.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - thisDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate;

Comment: How did you log the time intervals? It looks like you're printing an integer, but they're really doubles.

Comment: @Kevin - ok got it - here's a better log output - it highlights my dates are fundamentally slightly off - I wonder if this could be due to having some places where I use [NSDate date] to create a date and then set hours/minutes/seconds etc, but no realizing there are some subsecond components.    "isAfterThisDatee: Thu 03-11-2011 09:00:00 GMT+10:00 341967600.080772 is after Thu 03-11-2011 09:00:00 GMT+10:00 341967600.000000 is TRUE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally better to use

- the highest-level APIs that are available AND
- the most specific API available.

So in this case,  -earlierDate: or -laterDate: , if you're just going to use the resultant date object itself, or if you're just testing a given date, then yes, -timeIntervalSinceLastDate.

Generally speaking, formatters are only for generating human-readable forms of a value and not for doing operations on the values themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

(for reference - as Kevin pointed out - I hadn't appreciated the subseconds which were present in my dates)